# Pandas count number of rows in columns that start with upper case of are of specific length

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```py
data = [['male', 'A', NaN, something, something], ['Female', 'C', something, something, NaN], ['Male', 'B', something, something, something], ['female', 'Ca', something, something, NaN]] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Gender', 'Group', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'])
```

I want to be able to create another data frame which calculates 4 things across both the Gender and Group columns and 0 for other columns: the number of missing values, the percentage of those missing values, the number of columns that have an uppercase gender or a group longer than one letter, and the percentage of those.

I can do the first part:

```py
missing_values = df.isnull().sum()
percent_missing = df.isnull().sum() * 100 / len(df)

missing_values_df = pd.DataFrame({'Features': df.columns,
                                  'Missing Values (MV)': missing_values,
                                  '% of MV (MV/n)': percent_missing})
```

How would I calculate how many are incorrectly upper case gender and have more than one letter as a group?

I know that the following calculates the number of rows that have a gender that starts with an upper case, but I can't seem to include that into my `missing_values_df`.

```py
df['Uppercase'] = df['Gender'].str.findall(r'[A-Z]').str.len()
```

My expected output based on this example would be:

```py
Features, Missing Values, % of missing values, wrong case or group length, % of wrong data

gender         0                    0                         2            0.5
group          0                    0                         1            0.25
X              1                    0.25                      0            0
Y              0                    0                         0            0
Z              2                    0.5                       0            0
```

**Edit - more things I've tried:**

```
missing_values_df['wrong case or group length'] = (titanic_data.Gender.apply(lambda x: x.islower() == False).astype(int).sum())
```

This calculates the sum for the gender column but includes it as a row for every column in the missing values df. Is there a way to only associate this with the gender row and everything else stay as 0?

Comment: Python supports regex and you can use the re module to help. There's a good intro at https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp  I myself am not great at regex so I can't provide a solution, but hopefully this can help you figure it out

Answer (score 1):

First thing first.
I would use `str.islower()` instead of `str.findall(r'[A-Z]').str.len()` as the latter would return `n` in case you have `n` CAPS in one string.
That said, below is a step by step solution that will make it easier to follow the logic. You can easily wrap it in fewer lines of code:

```
data = [['male', 'A'], ['Female', 'C'], ['Male', 'B'], ['female', 'Ca']] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Gender', 'Group']) 

#df['Uppercase'] = (df['Gender'].str.islower()==False).astype(int) #in case you need this
#df['length']= (df['Group'].str.len()>1).astype(int)               #in case you need this

#Here we follow your logic and simply complete the df with the last two columns

missing_values = df.isnull().sum()
percent_missing = df.isnull().sum() * 100 / len(df)

missing_values_df = pd.DataFrame({'Features': df.columns.tolist(),
                                     'Missing Values (MV)': missing_values,
                                     '% of MV (MV/n)': percent_missing,
                                     'wrong case or group length':0,
                                     '% of wrong data':0})


#create a list
new_col=[(df['Gender'].str.islower()==False).astype(int).sum()]
#add an element to the list
new_col.extend([(df['Group'].str.len()>1).astype(int).sum()])

# the final column is simply the previous list divided by len(df)
new_col_ratio= [x / len(df) for x in new_col]

# add the columns to the missing_values_df dataframe
missing_values_df['wrong case or group length']=new_col
missing_values_df['% of wrong data']=new_col_ratio
```

The following modification works with OP updated MWE:

```
missing_values_df.loc[missing_values_df['Features']=='Gender','wrong case or group length']=(df['Gender'].str.islower()==False).astype(int).sum()

missing_values_df.loc[missing_values_df['Features']=='Group','wrong case or group length']=(df['Group'].str.len()>1).astype(int).sum()

new_col_ratio= [x / len(df) for x in missing_values_df['wrong case or group length']]

missing_values_df['% of wrong data']=new_col_ratio
```

Comment: This doesn't work - there's a dictionary within the dataframe missing_values_df and it throws an error. When I remove that, the adding of the new columns to the missing values df doesnt work because of a length problem?

Comment: @user47467 this works on the provided MWE. Update your question with the correct format of your dataframe otherwise we can't help you. This solution assumes you only have two rows (Gender and Group). The length problem is probably caused by a third row you haven't included in your example

Comment: Your current answer doesn't work for the MWE as there's an indent error due to the names of the columns in the missing_values_df because of the dictionary problem I mentioned before. If you remove the braces after percent missing, it works.

Comment: @user47467 I didn't notice the typo, I removed it. =). However, if you include all the columns in `df` as rows of `missing_values_df`, as in your new MWE, then the solution needs to be modified (see updated answer).